# Python program exits forcibly after subscribing to a streaming table in DolphinDB and adding data to the table

Tags: python, streaming, dolphindb

A Python program subscribes to a streaming table *singalTable* in a thread in DolphinDB and then attempts to insert data into the table using `tableInsert`. However, when the function is called, the Python program crashes and exits.

The last log of DolphinDB is as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IO_ERROR 1` message in the log indicates that the API has closed the connection. To solve this problem, two things need to be checked:

1. **Check whether the server and API versions are compatible**: To receive
   latest streaming data from the DolphinDB server after upgrading to
   version 2.00.9 or later, you need to make sure that the Python SDK
   is also upgraded to the corresponding version.
2. ****Check whether the same connection session is being used for writing
   data to and subscribing to the streaming table**:** Sessions are not
   thread-safe and this behaviour can lead to issues such as connection
   closure. So different sessions are needed for the two tasks.